# C# NetworkStream detect all kind of disconnections and exceptions

Tags: c#, encoding, buffer, networkstream

I have this code to connect to streaming server. the server disconnect from time to time and I want to detect it and restart the connection when neede.

How can I detect in this code any kind of exceptions?
Because now I get disconnected and can't catch it.

```
this.ns = new NetworkStream(server);
while (true)
{
    // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size. 
    do
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[10240 * 5];
        await this.ns.ReadAsync(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length).ContinueWith((numberOfBytesRead) =>
        {
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead.Result);
            p.Invoke(message);
        });
    }
    while (this.ns.DataAvailable);
}
```

Comment: If this code works as intended and you only want suggestions on possible improvements, you should post this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @s.m. not really, im getting exceptions and can't catch them...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code in try/catch for the right exceptions?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot catch them"?

Comment: @Evk Means that I the streaming stopps, the server booted me or maybe somehing in my side. Since evry thing is async, I can't catch and maybe reconnect

Comment: But you don't have even try-catch block in your code? And you can catch exceptions from `async ...` stuff as usual. By the way - never mix async with ContinueWith.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `numberOfBytesRead` is actually the previous task that has finished from where you can check whether it is completed or failed.

```
if(numberOfBytesRead.IsFaulted)
{
    var aggregatedEx = numberOfBytesRead.Exception;
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use `ContinueWith` here at all. `var numberOfBytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync(...); var message = ...`.